# how to install ruby 2.1.2 using RVM in ubuntu 11.10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu

I am trying to install ruby version 2.1.2 in UBUNTU 11.10 using RVM but i am facing issue. I used the below commands to install it:
**rvm install 2.1.2**

it hangs after below output:
rbx-2.1.2 installing #dependencies 
Cloning git://github.com/rubinius/rubinius.git

Could you please help me if there is any other way to install the same or i am making some mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try updating to latest version of rvm.

See https://rvm.io/rvm/upgrading

Answer (score 0):

`rbx-2.1.2` is different from `ruby-2.1.2`

Try `rvm install ruby-2.1.2` ?

Comment: I am still getting the error using above commnad. error is below:  Installing Ruby from source to: /home/sopra/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...

ruby-2.1.2 - #fetching 
ruby-2.1.2 - #downloading ruby-2.1.2-, this may take a while depending on your connection...
curl: (3) <url> malformed
There was an error,Next we'll try to fetch via http.
Trying ftp:// URL instead.
curl: (3) <url> malformed
There was an error, There has been an error while trying to fetch the source.  
Halting the installation.

Comment: That's probably because your rvm is installed by `apt-get`. Try `sudo apt-get uninstall ruby-rvm` and then `\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash` to install the latest rvm first.